# trouble getting docker image up and runnig

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I downloaded a hopsoft/graphite-statsd docker image yesterday.
when I go to the docker terminal now and enter `docker images`, I get:

```
bash-3.2$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
hello-world         latest              af340544ed62        2 weeks ago         960 B
<none>              <none>              89bd20e2deb3        3 weeks ago         785.7 MB
bash-3.2$
```

I am guessing that the `hopsoft/graphite-statsd` is the one labelled `<none>`

but when I open Kitematic (a GUI for docker), only hello-world was listed on my list of images. `hopsoft/graphite-statsd` was not listed.

On going to the terminal and trying to run the image as: `docker run 89bd20e2deb3`, I get the following:

```
bash-3.2$ docker run 89bd20e2deb3
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh...
No SSH host key available. Generating one...
Creating SSH2 RSA key; this may take some time ...
Creating SSH2 DSA key; this may take some time ...
Creating SSH2 ECDSA key; this may take some time ...
Creating SSH2 ED25519 key; this may take some time ...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of restart.
*** Running /etc/rc.local...
*** Booting runit daemon...
*** Runit started as PID 94
```

and it just hangs there.

so, I decided to remove it, and download it again.

However, on running `docker rmi 89bd20e2deb3`, I get the following:

```
bash-3.2$ docker rmi 89bd20e2deb3
Error response from daemon: Conflict, cannot delete because 89bd20e2deb3 is held by an ongoing pull or build
Error: failed to remove images: [89bd20e2deb3]
bash-3.2$
```

and now, I am out on my `docker-tricks` :). How can I get this image up and running on my machine? I really need all help I can get here.

Comment: The image labelled `<none>` is not `hopsoft/graphite-statsd`.  If you had that image, it would be labelled `hopsoft/graphite-statsd`.  This suggests that your `docker pull` may have failed.

Comment: now, when I try to run `docker pull hopsoft/graphite-statsd`, nothing happens, it just hangs. @larsks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incidentally (and this is a partial answer), when you see:

```
*** Running /etc/rc.local...
*** Booting runit daemon...
*** Runit started as PID 94
```

It's not "just hanging".  The container has booted `runit`, a process supervisor much like `init` or `systemd`, which presumably has then started additional processes inside the container.  You could see these doing something like:

```
pstree -p $(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' <container_id>)
```

Now, since 89bd20e2deb3 is an intermediate image (possibly a layer used by the graphite image you're trying to pull), it is entirely possible that `runit` is actually not starting anything else.

The key point here is that when you `docker run` an image you will not necessarily get some sort of interactive prompt.  The container may start network accessible services (such as an ssh server, or a web server), and you may need to interact with the container using that mechanism.

Based on the [documentation for hopsoft/graphite-stats](https://hub.docker.com/r/hopsoft/graphite-statsd/), this appears to be the case for that image.  The docs provide a list of ports on which services are listening.

But you haven't been able to successfully pull the image.  Clues to the problem may be found in your docker daemon logs...and where to find these depends a bit on your distribution.  In a `systemd` world, the answer is `journalctl -b -u docker`.  In a legacy environment, logs may be found wherever syslog is putting them (maybe `/var/log/messages` or similar).

Comment: Okay, so I just decided to reboot my machine so as to stop all processes, and then by the time I reboot, and tried to `docker rmi <image-id>`, I was able to successfully remove it, and then the `docker pull` command worked right. Thanks @larsks all seems fine now :).